# Limit of addition mapping at a point $(a,\infty)$ w.r.t. $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ is $\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

> With respect to $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$, the function
> $(x,y)\mapsto x+y$ has a limit at every point $(a,b)$ of
> $\overline{\mathbb{R}}\times\overline{\mathbb{R}}$, except at the
> points $(-\infty,\infty)$ and $(\infty,-\infty)$.

Take $(a,\infty)\in\overline{\mathbb{R}}\times\overline{\mathbb{R}}$. We want to show that
$$\lim_{(x_1,x_2)\rightarrow(a,\infty),\,(x_1,x_2)\in\overline{\mathbb{R}}\times\overline{\mathbb{R}}}x_1+x_2=\infty.$$
Let $0<\varepsilon$. We have to find a $\delta>0$ such that $d_{\overline{\mathbb{R}}\times\overline{\mathbb{R}}}((x_1,x_2),(a,\infty))<\delta$ implies $x_1+x_2<\varepsilon$ for all $(x_1,x_2)\in\overline{\mathbb{R}}\times\overline{\mathbb{R}}$. How to choose $\delta$? Dieudonne says the following:

> Given $c\in\mathbb{R}$, the relations $b<x$ and $c-b<y$ imply $c<x+y$,
> and the intervals $(b,\infty]$ and $(c-b,\infty]$ are respectively
> neighborhoods of $a$ and $\infty$ if $b$ is taken finite and $<a$.

How can I use this to find a $\delta>0$ for which the required property holds?

*Note: $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ denotes the extended real line. Furthermore, the metric on $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is defined as follows:
$$d_{\overline{\mathbb{R}}}(x,y):=|f(x)-f(y)|,$$
where $f:x\mapsto x/(1+|x|)$, $f(\infty)=1$ and $f(-\infty)=-1$.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Choose $c\in\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
|f(c)-1| < \varepsilon
$$
(this is possible because $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=1$). Note that, because $f$ is increasing, then
$$
|f(x)-1| < \varepsilon, \qquad \text{for all } x>c.
$$
Let $b\in\mathbb{R}$ with $b<a$, and let
$$
\delta = \min(f(a)-f(b),1-f(c-b)).
$$
Then if $d_{\overline{\mathbb{R}}\times \overline{\mathbb{R}}}((x,y),(a,\infty))< \delta$, then
$$
d_\overline{\mathbb{R}}(x,a)< \delta \quad \text{and} \quad d_\overline{\mathbb{R}}(y,\infty) < \delta,
$$
which implies that
$$
|f(x) - f(a)| < f(a) - f(b) \quad \text{and} \quad |1-f(y)| < 1-f(c-b)
$$
and, in particular,
$$
f(b) < f(x) \quad \text{and} \quad f(c-b) < f(y).
$$
As $f$ is increasing, this means that
$$
b < x \quad \text{and} \quad c-b < y
$$
from which $c = b + (c-b) < x+y$, and hence $|f(x+y)-1|<\varepsilon$. This means that
$$
d_{\overline{\mathbb{R}}}(x+y,\infty) < \varepsilon,
$$
as you desired.

**Remark:** You don't have to show that $d((x_1,x_2),(a,\infty))<\delta$ implies $x_1+x_2<\varepsilon$. You have to show that $d((x_1,x_2),(a,\infty))<\delta$ implies $d(x_1+x_2,\infty)<\varepsilon$.

Comment: I didn't mean that you had to delete the answer! Just change it a bit so that it leaves some work to the OP! Cheers!